# DF - Sorting specific columns based on character code values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have below dataframe and I need to perform sort based on 6th, 3rd and 4th column values.
sorting should be based on ASCII character code corresponding to the column values.
""ASCII Character code is Digits are the lowest value characters and followed by uppercase letter, followed by lowercase letters""

```
USOM04200||RCT|19000|99991|13184745|FRML HR RMVR WAX STRP KIT BOX 28 CT|94|I
USOM02100||RCT|19000|99991|13184745|FRML HR RMVR WAX STRP KIT BOX 28 CT|94|I
USOM04200||RCT|19000|99991|13184745|FRML HR RMVR WAX STRP KIT BOX 28 CT|94|I
0638995||UPC|19000|99991|13184745|FRML HR RMVR WAX STRP KIT BOX 28 CT|94|I
USOM00330||RCT|19000|99991|13184745|FRML HR RMVR WAX STRP KIT BOX 28 CT|94|I
USOM00308||RCT|19000|99991|26746352|TXTR HT PLSH CAN 4 OZ|94|I
USOM04300||RCT|19000|99991|26746352|TXTR HT PLSH CAN 4 OZ|94|I
USOM04200||RCT|19000|99991|26746352|TXTR HT PLSH CAN 4 OZ|94|I
0685428||UPC|19000|99991|26746352|TXTR HT PLSH CAN 4 OZ|94|I
```

After character code based sorting output will be as below

```
USOM00330||RCT|19000|99991|13184745|FRML HR RMVR WAX STRP KIT BOX 28 CT|94|I
USOM04200||RCT|19000|99991|13184745|FRML HR RMVR WAX STRP KIT BOX 28 CT|94|I
USOM04200||RCT|19000|99991|13184745|FRML HR RMVR WAX STRP KIT BOX 28 CT|94|I
USOM02100||RCT|19000|99991|13184745|FRML HR RMVR WAX STRP KIT BOX 28 CT|94|I
0638995||UPC|19000|99991|13184745|FRML HR RMVR WAX STRP KIT BOX 28 CT|94|I
USOM04300||RCT|19000|99991|26746352|TXTR HT PLSH CAN 4 OZ|94|I
USOM00308||RCT|19000|99991|26746352|TXTR HT PLSH CAN 4 OZ|94|I
USOM04200||RCT|19000|99991|26746352|TXTR HT PLSH CAN 4 OZ|94|I
0685428||UPC|19000|99991|26746352|TXTR HT PLSH CAN 4 OZ|94|I
```

This is how I read DF

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('input.txt', sep='|', names=['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'])
```

Could someone help pls

Comment: Please include your expected output

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something this is as simple as using [.sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

```py
df1.sort_values(["6","3","4"])
```

use `inplace=True` or `ascending=[bool,bool,bool]` as needed.

Comment: sorry, this is right if dont consider ascii character code of column values. here not column values instead character code of column values has to be sorted

Comment: so ascii character codes just work for strings of length one, how do you want this sorted? the sum of the ascii character codes for a string?

Comment: based on character code values in which sequence they are arranged. may be sum also will work

Comment: sorted (the underlying function for sort_values) does exactly this.

Your example data has the same 3rd and 4th column values for all of the data, so ascii sorting your dataframe on the 6th, 4th and 3rd column values (which is what sort_values does) won't produce the sample output you provided.

Comment: sorry, pls start courting from 1 instead 0

Comment: RCT is 3rd column

Comment: gotcha, when you named your columns you named that column '2', which confused me